# How to get last six month's data in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am developing one chart in that chart I want to show last six month's details separately.
I want to show the details in bar chart.

But I am not getting the any solution. 
I am bit weak in sql queries.

Till now I got the data for last month.
But I want the data for last six month.
here's my code.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @StartDate)

SELECT  sum(quantity)
FROM RS_Sell_Order_Master as s
left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Mapping as sm on sm.sell_order_no = s.sell_order_no 
left outer join RS_GIN_Master as GIN on gin.product_id = sm.product_id 

WHERE del_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

I want o/p of last six month like this suppose I have sell 10 quantity last month & 20 prevous to that month & I didnt sell before that So o/p should be

```
null
null
null
null
10
20
```

some thing like this.

Comment: What do you think this is doing: `DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate())-1`?  With that in mind, how do you think you would get the last 6 months instead of the last 1 month?

Comment: Do you mean to start the query on the 1st of the month, or on the same date as today, 6 months ago?

Comment: I know this whole query is wrong I dont think so that I will get required output  by this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will assign a date exactly 6 months ago - there doesn't seem to be a reason why you would need to go back to the zero datum of SqlServer's `DATETIME`:

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

**Edit**

Assuming that you want month's aligned from the first to the end of each month,
and assuming because you have nulls but still want to show data that we will need to manufacture the missing months (e.g. with a recursive CTE)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm, -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS TheMonth
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TheMonth + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE TheMonth < 5
)
SELECT sum(quantity)
FROM
    cte 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RS_Sell_Order_Master as s
    ON del_date >= DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth, @StartDate) AND del_date < DATEADD(MM, cte.TheMonth + 1, @StartDate)
    -- Other Joins here
GROUP BY cte.TheMonth
ORDER BY cte.TheMonth;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f407a/11)

Comment: I appreciate your effort, Stuart. But I want sum of each month's quantity. Suppose I have sell 20 in last Month & 10 in previous that month o/p should be first four month should be null & then second last month will be 20 & last month o/p should  be 10

Comment: Thank you for your efforts StuartLC

Comment: Updated to group the last 6 month's data - (apols, was a typo in my previous update)

Comment: I was doing this from last 2-3 days. You have solved this in 2 min . great.. Awesome....!!!!! Keep It up Dud

Answer (score 0):

total no of items per month can be calculated like

```
select sum(items),left(date,6)+'01' from yourTable
group by left(date,6)
```

assuming your date is in 112 format....and it is of varchar(8) type..

Comment: It is saying invalid column name date

Comment: replace date by your column which is holding time values... i think it is 'TheMonth' ... try it